# How to avoid namespaces dependency cycles between my entities?

Tags: entity-framework, namespaces, ndepend

I analysed my code with NDepend and it detected some critical rules one of them is: "**Avoid namespaces mutually dependent**".

But I can't figure how I can organize my code to get rid of this "errors", in the case of navigation properties.

Of course I could place all my entities in the same namespace, but I think my actual "by namespace" class separation organization is not so bad.

Maybe I have to ignore this message and exclude my persistence assembly of the ndepend scan.

What am I missing?

first class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Persistence.Entities.ContactModule;

namespace Persistence.Entities.TeachingModule
{
    public class Course
    {        
        private Course() { }
        public Course(string reference,Company company )
        {
            this.Reference = reference ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reference));
            this.Company = company ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(company));
        }
        public int Id { get; private set; } 
        public string Reference { get; private set; } = null!;
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

Second class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Persistence.Entities.TeachingModule;

namespace Persistence.Entities.ContactModule
{
    public class Company
    {        
        private Company() { }
        public Company(string reference, string name)
        {
            this.Reference = reference ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(reference));
            this.Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
        }
        public int Id { get; private set; } 
        public string Name { get; private set; } = null!;        
        public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The rule should help you to create layered code instead of spaghetti. In the end I think all of your entities are in just one layer: `Persistence.Entities`, so IMO the module namespaces don't add much, also because you're not going to have the same class names in different namespaces. Well, in fact this is all primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Gert Arnold suggestion sounds good. You can also use some interfaces ICourse ICompany in a third namespace referenced by both namespaces, and use these interfaces in your classes.